# How to merge multiple rows of same dataframe? Or How to merge multiple values of same key pair in python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

```
data = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 3},{'b':4},{'b':5}, {'c': 5}, {'c':5}]
```

If i have such a data which is then converted to dataframe, how do i merge the key value pair such that i obtain this dataframe

```
index       data_title            values                                                  
0               a                   1                 
1               b                 3,4,5                  
2               c                   5
```

Comment: Try `data = {'value':{'a': [0], 'b': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [4, 5]}}` or `data = {
    'data_title': ['a','b','b','b','c','c'],'value' : [1,3,4,5,5,5]
}` with `gropby('data_title')` just convert your data to folloing format by doing some loop magic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below code should help you solve your problem. If you need list of the aggregated values go for option2 but if you need string of aggregated values go for option 1

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 3}, {'b': 4}, {'b': 5}, {'c': 5}, {'c': 5}]

#converting list of Dict into dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([(i, j) for a in data for i, j in a.items()],
                  columns=['data_title', 'values'])

#option 1 : for converting the aggregate column into a string of conc values
df_str = df.groupby('data_title').aggregate(
    lambda x: ', '.join(map(str, set(x)))).reset_index()

print(df_str)

#option 2 :  for converting the aggregate column into a list of conc values
df_aslist = df.groupby('data_title').aggregate(lambda x: list(x)).reset_index()

print(df_aslist)
```

Output:

```
Option 1:
  data_title   values
0          a        1
1          b  3, 4, 5
2          c        5

Option 2:
  data_title     values
0          a        [1]
1          b  [3, 4, 5]
2          c     [5, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one method of getting what you're asking for. I'm not sure why, exactly, you'd want to get that output, but I'm sure you've got a good reason.  :)

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 3},{'b':4},{'b':5}, {'c': 5}, {'c':5}]

# Convert to Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# At first, your data look like this
print(df)
     a    b    c
0  1.0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  3.0  NaN
2  NaN  4.0  NaN
3  NaN  5.0  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  5.0
5  NaN  NaN  5.0

# Now chain a few operations together:
# 1) "stack" the values to go from a "wide" data format to a "tall, narrow" format
# 2) reset the index so we have only columns, not a Pandas index
# 3) drop the first column (the old index) called "level_0"
df2 = df.stack().reset_index().drop(columns='level_0')

# Assign better names to the columns:
df2.columns = ('data_title', 'values')
```

df2 now looks like this:

```
print(df2)
  data_title  values
0          a     1.0
1          b     3.0
2          b     4.0
3          b     5.0
4          c     5.0
5          c     5.0
```

Now to find the unique values, grouped by each `data_title`:

```
# Group by the "data_title" column, and find unique values from the "values" column
# Then reset the index again
df3 = df2.groupby('data_title')['values'].unique().reset_index()
```

That gives you this, where each "values" record is a Python `list` of unique values:

```
print(df3)
  data_title           values
0          a            [1.0]
1          b  [3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
2          c            [5.0]
```

I think the bigger question is, however, what are you actually trying to accomplish? What's next after this? I'm guessing if I knew the answer to that larger question, we could take a more direct route to your destination.

It reminds me of the joke where someone in Ireland asks how to get to Dublin, and the man replies "I wouldn't start here".  :)

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there might be more simpler approach than this, with some basic list comprehension you can get results too.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 3},{'b':4},{'b':5}, {'c': 5}, {'c':5}]

data = {
    'data_title':[k for o in data for k in list(o.keys())],
    'value':[v for o in data for v in list(o.values())] 
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.groupby('data_title')['value'].unique().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you would need to get rid of the `NaN` values as those will not allow you to combine numbers the way you want:
`T` will transpose the DataFrame and switch columns with rows and `stack` will put all the columns into one column creating multi index:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.T.stack()) 

        0
a   0   1.0
b   1   3.0
    2   4.0
    3   5.0
c   4   5.0
    5   5.0
```

Resetting an index will allow you to extract the correct column values

```
df2 = df2.reset_index()[['level_0', 0]]
```

Because you wanted to have the values joined with `,` you would need to convert the type to str. Note that `.astype(int)` will remove the `decimal` points from values

```
df2[0] = df2[0].astype(int).astype(str)

   level_0  0
0      a    1
1      b    3
2      b    4
3      b    5
4      c    5
5      c    5
```

Now you can use `group_by` to put the unique values from column `0` together ardound `level_0` column:

```
df2 = df2.groupby(by='level_0', axis=0)[0].unique().apply(','.join)
```

As you have only one column at this stage the df2 becomes `Series` and we need to convert it back to `Dataframe` and do final `reset_index`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2).reset_index()

    level_0 0
0      a    1
1      b    3,4,5
2      c    5
```

From here you can change the column names and this should match the results you wanted.

```
df2.rename(columns={'level_0':'data_title', 0:'values'}, inplace=True)
```